# JQuery mobile Search inputs Icon

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I was wondering whats the best way to make this magnifying glass Icon in to clickable button?
without changing the JQuery framework

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/forms/forms-search.html

This is where it's mapped in the framework

```
if( input.is('[type="search"],[data-type="search"]') 
focusedEl = input.wrap('<div class="ui-input-search ui-shadow-inset ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-shadow ui-icon-search'+ themeclass +'"></div>').parent();
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing anything with a javascript hack will destroy the whole **[progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement)** idea.

Just create a normal submit button and wrap it with a `<span class="maglass">` and then just crete some CSS rules with `!important` at the end to overwrite the jQuery Mobile button styles for the elements jqm creates to replace the submit button (inspect it with firebug to get the grip of what is created there)
And finally - if you want tit to look good in half-supported browsers you will have to get one of these and add yet another CSS rule.

Done. There's the button for not supported browsers and it enhances to a magnifying glass with CSS. Works everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can tell it's a div themed with an input element. That being said, you can probably do one of two things:

Bind to the input's wrapper such as:

```
$('__INPUT_SELECTOR__') // grab the input field
  .closest('div')       // traverse up to the parent div
  .bind('click',function(){
    // grab the click event and make it a form submit
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
  });
```

OR, you go the other direction:

```
$('div.ui-input-search') // find the div first
  .bind('click',function(){
    // now you have a click event on the div. Transfer it to the form's submit
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
  });
```

Just depends the direction you want to go. (And probably should be using the jquerymobile events, not classic jQuery ones (so you can catch figner taps, etc.)) Also, this should be interpreted as **pseudo-code** as I am not familiar with the library, just going with what I know.

**EDIT**
And so it's clear, I realize more has to be done (in terms of checking) for the DIV's click event. You would need to test the click was actually performed on the DIV not the input which results in a DIV event fire.
*Just throwing it out there to avoid "this doesn't work" comments. This is why it's pseudo-code.*